# convert JSON object to MySQL polygon datatype

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the coordinates of polygon drawn in google map in JSON object. And I am able to save them in MySQL database.

But I want to save them in polygon type for further spatial processing using this code-

```
$conn = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
$Latitudes   = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Latitudes']);
$Longitudes  = $conn->real_escape_string($_POST['Longitudes']);
$query   = "INSERT into table_name (Latitudes,Longitudes) VALUES(PolygonFromText('" . 
$Latitudes . "','" . $Longitudes . "'))";
```

But the error message is-**Cannot get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field** Or **Syntax error**

Please someone correct me.

Thanks!

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/populating-spatial-columns.html

Comment: I looked to that source but there they are giving coordinates manually, that is not my case.

Comment: It appears you are, what does `$Latitudes` and `$Longitudes` contain???

Comment: they contain a list of latitudes and longitudes. As-"[40.38002840251183,31.278550858946534]"

Comment: And what example have you seen of `PolygonFromText()` accepting just that and not the format in the link I posted?

Comment: please dont be so strict,I am new to this! 
Do you want to say that I should use ST_PolygonFromText in place of PolygonFromText?

Comment: If I am using this-
SET @g = 'POLYGON('" . $Latitudes . "','" . $Longitudes . "')';
$query   = "INSERT into final (Latitudes,Longitudes) VALUES(ST_PolygonFromText(@g))";
Then it shows-syntax error, unexpected @  on line 1(@g)